# Flexbox layout with dropwdown and buttons

Tags: javascript, css, layout, flexbox

I'm trying to do a simple layout using FlexBox. I search similar question but I can't find what can help me. I'm sorry if there is something similar.

My goal is:

[image]

`label A`, `dropdown menu` and `label B` (not `buttons`) should be resize when screen resize itself but `label A` and `label B` text should be always on a single line.
On mobile, I would like that `label B` and `buttons` are in a new row.

The layout must be responsive: when width of screen become smaller, the dropdown div should be smaller. If all the elements are greater than the size of the screen, then `label B` and the four buttons should be on a new row.

I try to use Flexbox.

This is my simple code:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center; 
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.button {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Label A</div>
  
  <div>Dropdown menu</div> 
  
  <div>Label B</div>
  
  <div>
    <div class="button">Button 1</div>
    <div class="button">Button 2</div>
    <div class="button">Button 3</div>
    <div class="button">Button 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, there are some problems.

I try `wrap` but i want that `buttons` are always together.

I'm a begginer so I need help. I read [this beautiful article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) about flex but I have still problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i added `button-block` class to buttons and added below css.
.button-block {
  display: flex;
}

also added `flex-wrap: wrap;` to .container class.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.button {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: gray;
}

.button-block {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Label A</div>
  
  <div>Dropdown menu</div> 
  
  <div>Label B</div>
  
  <div class="button-block ">
    <div class="button">Button 1</div>
    <div class="button">Button 2</div>
    <div class="button">Button 3</div>
    <div class="button">Button 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to achieve?

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center; 
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.button {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: gray;
}
#button-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

and

```
<div class="container">
  <div>Label A</div>

  <div>Dropdown menu</div> 

  <div>Label B</div>

  <div id="button-row">
    <div class="button">Button 1</div>
    <div class="button">Button 2</div>
    <div class="button">Button 3</div>
    <div class="button">Button 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sek0q4vL/

Comment: Thanks Eli for your reply but your code doesn't work :/

Comment: the accepted answer is literally the same as mine, oh well